# Ads not shown in the application

Tags: android, admob, android-xml

I have this in my xml file,

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="aa412a69718d40e1"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>
```

But, when I run my app on a device, [My app is on the play store ] , it doesn't show ads. What's the error?

Comment: 1. Have you checked the rate of AD or whether the ad is active in Admob wetsite?
2. You should put all layout xml and code for ad.

Comment: would you please elaborate?

Comment: Have you included `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"` at the top of the xml layout file?

Comment: Please provide us with the Logcat with tag "Ads" While you are running the app. Please use test Ads while your testing your App. As test Ads will be available always so you dont need to worry about Ad inventory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [out the link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ll8uYcH6Ex8)

Also [check out this link](http://developer.android.com/training/monetization/ads-and-ux.html) straight from developer.android

Hope this helps

**Edit:-**

From the code snippet, you have provided, I can only understand that you are missing **one important statement** i.e. `xmlns:googleads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"` in your com.google.ads.AdView section of xml file.

But I am not sure that's the only issue . SO, please **check my second link**, You will find a sample project to download. You will gt better idea..

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please add the actual answer or parts of it.

Comment: He has not included the complete code Snippet. the 'xmlns:googleads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"' can also be included in the Main Layout. If he had not, the error would be different. And he would not be able to run his App.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that some users may use `ADBlock` or just edited `/system/etc/hosts` file, if the device is rooted.